# Grabbing brackets and everything inside Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am reading a line that has the following format

```
.... .... [..*stuff*..].... ... .... .... [*stuff*] ... ... [*stuff*]
```

Where the dots `...` and `*stuff*` are just numbers and text

I am trying to extract only the first instance of the bracketed text/numbers as well as the brackets themselves

so...

`[..*stuff*..]`

Currently, my code does this but sometimes if there is more then one set of brackets, it will extract everything after the first set of brackets.

This means that when I want everything inside the first set of brackets it will also print out the remainder of the string

`[*stuff*]...........[*sutff*].....[*stuff*]`

when i just want the first set of brackets and everything inside.

The regular expression I am using is `BracketedRegex = re.compile(r'\[.*\]')`.

my code:

```
BracketedRegex = re.compile(r'\[.*\]')

f = open("logfile.log","r")

for line in f.readlines():
    Bracket = re.search(BracketedRegex,line)
    if Bracket:
        print Bracket.group()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your regex non-greedy:

```
BracketedRegex = re.compile(r'\[.*?\]')
```

The `*?` quantifier will match the *least* number of characters that satisfy the pattern, as opposed to `*` which will match the *maximum* number.

Alternatively, you could match anything that is not a closing bracket (instead of the `.` meta character):

```
BracketedRegex = re.compile(r'\[[^\]]*\]')
```

where the `[^..]` negative character class matches anything not a member of the class, e.g. anything *not* a `]` character.

Comment: There seem to be people out there who believe non-greedy regexps are always the wrong solution, no matter what, although I've never understood why they think that… This is pretty much the paradigm case for using them.

Comment: @abarnert: except another recent `[regex]` answer of mine was also downvoted, one that didn't use `*` vs. `*?`. Perhaps someone doesn't like me answering regular expression questions.